# Expect Script - detecting two unique instances of a pattern in one returned buffer

Tags: regex, expect

I'm trying to do two matches on one block returned data inside an expect script.  This is the returned data from a command shows what this system is connected to(I changed the descriptions to protect sensitive information).  I thought I could use expect_out(buffer), but I can't figure out how to parse the returned data to detect two unique instances of the patterns.  I can re-run the command if I detect one instance a pattern, but that won't allow me to detect the case where I have two unique instances of a pattern in the returned data as expect{} would re-find the first pattern.  For example 'abcd' and 'abcd'.

Case one: I will have zero instances of 'abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', or 'qurs' in the returned block - in that case nothing will be written to a file and that's fine.

Case two: I will have only once instance of 'abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', or 'qurs' in the file, the current code detects that case and then writes the existence of one pattern to a file for later processing.

Case three: I have two instances of the patterns 'abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl', 'mnop', or 'qurs', in any combination of the pairs.  I could have 'abcd', 'abcd'; 'abcd', 'efgh'; or  'ijkl', 'mnop'.  If case 3 happens I need to write a different message to the file.

Can anyone help?

My data:

```
  A4        |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A15       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A16       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A17       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A18       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A19       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A20       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A21       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  A24       | abcd                       
  A24       |                                            abcd
  B1        |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  B2        |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  B3        |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  B4        |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  B5        |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  B6        |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  B21       |                           48     48        changedToProtectPrivacy
  B24       | abcd             
  B24       |                                            abcd
  D2        |                           00 ... 1         changedToProtectPrivacy
  D10       |                           00 ... 1         changedToProtectPrivacy
  E6        |                           00 ... 1         changedToProtectPrivacy
```

-=- Current code snippit -=-

```
expect { "prompt" } send { "superSecretCommand" ; sleep 2 }
expect {
                        "abcd" { set infofile "info.$server" ;
                                set ::infofile [open $infofile a] ;
                                puts $::infofile  "Connection detected" ;
                                close  $::infofile ;
                                }

                        "efgh" { set infofile "info.$server" ;
                                set ::infofile [open $infofile a] ;
                                puts $::infofile  "Connection detected" ;
                                close  $::infofile ;
                                }
}
```

Comment: The output shown by you has four occurrences of 'abcd'. Then what is your expectation on that ? Or, do we have to take it like 2 instances of 'abcd' for 2 times ?

Comment: That is a good point I missed.  I think it has to be 2 instances of 'abcd' 2 times sadly.  I wish I could fix the output so it does not duplicate the line but I can't edit that source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is like this:

```
[STEP 101] $ cat infile
  A20 |      48     48 changedToProtectPrivacy
  A21 |      48     48 changedToProtectPrivacy
  A24 | abcd
  A24 |                abcd
  B1  |      48     48 changedToProtectPrivacy
  B6  |      48     48 changedToProtectPrivacy
  B7  | ijkl
  B21 |      48     48 changedToProtectPrivacy
  B24 | efgh
  B24 |                abcd
  D2  |      00 ... 1  changedToProtectPrivacy
  D3  | efgh
  D3  |                abcd
  D10 |      00 ... 1  changedToProtectPrivacy
  D11 | ijkl
  E6  |      00 ... 1  changedToProtectPrivacy
  E7  | ijkl
[STEP 102] $ cat foo.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect

log_user 0
spawn -noecho cat infile
set pat1 {[\r\n]+[[:blank:]]*[A-Z][0-9]+[[:blank:]]*\|[[:blank:]]*}
set pat2 {[a-z]{4,4}}
expect {
    -re "${pat1}($pat2)${pat1}($pat2)|${pat1}($pat2)" {
        if {[info exists expect_out(3,string)]} {
            send_user ">>> $expect_out(3,string)\n"
        } else {
            send_user ">>> $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string)\n"
        }
        array unset expect_out
        exp_continue
    }
}
[STEP 103] $ expect foo.exp
>>> abcd abcd
>>> ijkl
>>> efgh abcd
>>> efgh abcd
>>> ijkl
>>> ijkl
[STEP 104] $
```